# sql query executes in sql server, but not on program

Tags: .net, sql-server

i have this query in my program:

```
String userSearchCommand = " select M.Title, " +
" cast(cast(cast(M.Time as float)/3600 as int) as varchar(20)) +':' " +
" +cast(cast((cast(cast(M.Time as float) as int)/60)%60 as int) as varchar(20))+':' " +
" +cast(cast(cast(cast(M.Time as float)as int)%60 as int) as varchar(20)) As WatchTime " +
" from ( select Videos.title, MAX(logging.playtime) as Time from logging " +
" inner join Videos on Videos.number = logging.viewing " +
" where username= ' " +user+ " ' and logtype = '1' and logdate>CONVERT(varchar,' " +from+ " ',110) and logdate<CONVERT(varchar,' " +to+ " ',110) " +
" group by Videos.title) M " +
" order by M.Time Desc ";
```

when i put specific values it executes as it should, but when i put variables, it  doesn'y seem to output data... can anybody help me please?

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Could you show us what you mean by "put variables" as compared to "put specific values?"

Comment: @MatthewHaugen if i try to run the program for example, "where user='user1'and logtype = '1' and logdate>CONVERT(varchar,'01/04/2014  ',110) and logdate<CONVERT(varchar,' 01/05/2014 ',110) it outputs the table with the specific data.

Comment: Interesting. Well I think @marc_s's suggestion here might do the trick for you. It's good practice in general, but this definitely sounds like the kind of bug that parameterizing could resolve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should **always** use **parametrized queries** - do **NOT** build your SQL commands yourself as strings, including unvalidated user input! This will lead to SQL injection attacks - the most common web attack ever. Just don't do it.

So instead of building your SQL command as you do know, use something like this:

```
string userSearchCommand = 
    @"SELECT M.Title, 
      cast(cast(cast(M.Time as float)/3600 as int) as varchar(20)) + ':' +
      cast(cast((cast(cast(M.Time as float) as int)/60)%60 as int) as varchar(20))  + ':' +
      cast(cast(cast(cast(M.Time as float)as int)%60 as int) as varchar(20)) As WatchTime 
     FROM 
        (SELECT 
            Videos.title, MAX(logging.playtime) as Time 
         FROM 
            logging 
         INNER JOIN 
            Videos ON Videos.number = logging.viewing 
         WHERE 
            username = @UserName
            AND logtype = '1' 
            AND logdate > @FromDate
            AND logdate < @ToDate
         GROUP BY 
            Videos.title) M 
    ORDER BY 
        M.Time DESC";

// create your connection and command, use the parametrized query text
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(..your connection string here....))
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand (userSearchCommand, conn))
{
    // define the properties and set their values
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = ".....";
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@FromDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = ".....";
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@ToDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = ".....";

    // open connection, execute query
    conn.Open();

    using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        // read the values
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            // do something with the values returned from the query
        }

        reader.Close();
    }

    conn.Close();
}
```

Using this, you **avoid** any possibility of SQL injection, because you're using parameters, the query plan will be reused and the second and third execution of this search query will be faster, and since you're using the **appropriate** datatypes, you avoid any issues with date-to-string conversion, escaping single quotes in strings and all the other messy issues that you have when just stringing together your SQL commands manually.